# What does scanf REMOVES from input after scanning?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I have gone through many questions and blogs and books, but I guess I'm just not able to relate things properly.
What does scanf do after scanning? It reads everything except space, tab and newline, but what does it do to newline?? 
I'm unable to remove newline any way after scanning input.
For example, consider this as input:-

5

Abcdefgh

Now, I have scanned 5 as integer,

```
 scanf("%d", &i);
```

but how do I remove '\n' in order to read everything ahead one character at a time? I want to use:-

```
 while((c=getchar())!='\n'){//Do something}
```

The '\n' is supposed to be the one AFTER the string, but getchar() gets the one after 5 and loop terminates before even running once. I guess I'm just missing a very little trick.

```
scanf("%d", &i);
while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
    //Do something with the character
}
```

Input File:-
5
ABCDEF

Expecting while loop to run, while it doesn't run. Because it catches '\n' after 5. I have tried adding getchar() in between scanf() and while(), but then program stucks and does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a space after the `%d` in your `scanf` format specifier, `scanf` will not return until it encounters any non-whitespace character. This will effectively consume any number of newlines or other spaces in your input. As pointed out by @BlueMoon, note that this **relies** on the program receiving more non-whitespace input after the newline. So it works for this example but might cause trouble elsewhere.

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j=0;
    char c;
    scanf("%d ", &i);
    while((c=getchar())!='\n') printf("%d: %c\n", j++, c);    
    return 0;
}
```

sample input:

```
5   


abcdefg
```

output:

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e
5: f
6: g
```

---

**edit**: Note that this issue can be circumvented by using `fgets` to read a line into a character buffer, then extracting the integer using `sscanf`:

```
char buff[SIZE];
fgets(buff, SIZE, stdin);
sscanf(buff, "%d ", &i);
while((c=getchar())!='\n') printf("%d: %c\n", j++, c);
```

`fgets` reads until a newline or end of file is encountered, or `SIZE-1` bytes have been read. Assuming you're only expecting the line to contain one integer, this limitation shouldn't be an issue. As long as `SIZE` is large enough, the newline will be consumed by `fgets` and the subsequent `getchar` in the loop will work as expected.

Comment: `If you want to consume all whitespace until other characters are entered, you can just add a space after the %d`. No. Here scanf() just waits for you to enter a non-whitespace character and doesn't terminate until you do so.

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm afraid I don't understand the distinction. Is there a possible negative side-effect to this approach? Besides, doesn't this do exactly what the OP was after?

Comment: The distinction is that it is *necessary* to input a non-white space char to terminate scanf(). Consuming whitespaces left, if any, is different than mandating to input a non-whitespace char.

Comment: @BlueMoon good point, I see what you mean, thanks. I've updated the answer so that hopefully it explains a bit better.

Comment: The OP clearly stated that there is a new line after the integer, so I think the `"%d "` thing works fine as an answer for this question.

Comment: @ace more importantly, further input is expected after the newline so the program will continue beyond the `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Windows, there is a `'\r'` character before the `'\n'` character.

The "adding a `getchar();` before your `while` loop" trick doesn't work because this `getchar()` is getting the `'\r'` character. So when the `while` condition is first evaluated, `c` is `'\n'`.

So a trivial fix would be to use TWO `getchar()` calls to consume the `'\r\n'`. However, this is not very portable, that is, it won't work on other systems.

So I would use the following:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char c;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(getchar()=='\r') getchar();
    while((c=getchar())!='\n') {
        printf("%c\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good distinguish between EOL in Windows/Unix-line OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `getchar()` right after the `scanf()` call to consume the `\n` so that it doesn't interfere with your loop.

```
scanf("%d", &i); 
getchar(); // To consume the trailing newline left 
           //in the input stream by scanf().

 while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
   //Do something
 }
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j=0;
    char c;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    getchar();
    printf("%d\n", i);

    while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
      printf("%c-", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I ran the above code in the same as you do: `./a.out < file` on Linux and on windows using `mingw` and I don't see any problem.

Comment: Someone else answered the same. I myself tried the same. But this just isn't working. Not on Windows at least. I tried '\r\n'. '\r' alone. Nothing.

Comment: Can you post your code? You don't need to use `\r\n`. Are you sure you don't have any other scanf() calls similar to this before your loop?

Comment: No additional scanf() calls. Just one scanf() call, then call to another function which is using getchar().

Comment: Reading your comments, you seem to be reading from a file rather than stdin. In that case, you shouldn't have any problem. But shouldn't you be using `fscanf()` to read *from file* ?

Comment: I'm not reading from a file, I'm just feeding input from a file. 
Program.exe <in.txt >out.txt

Comment: @vish213 What compiler are you using? I can't reproduce the problem as you described.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks and its using GNU GCC compiler. I'm trying other things too. Trying your code now. Posting results in 5 minutes.

Comment: Negative. I'm on Windows 8 32-bit. Copied pasted your code, generated an exe file, named testingGetchar.exe. Opened command prompt and ran it testingGetchar.exe <in.txt >out.txt  . It stucked. Please tell me what can I do more to explain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51898/discussion-between-vish213-and-blue-moon)

Answer (score 0):

If you take character or string inputs, use `getchar()` after every integer inputs. This will remove the `\n` from the input buffer.

```
scanf("%d", &i);
getchar();
while((c=getchar())!='\n'){//Do something}
```

Comment: How would it behave in case I'm feeding input from a text file? Because it stucks at this very line. I tried this.

Comment: If you are taking input from a text file, you are not using `getchar()`. What are you using then?

Comment: I mean I'm using getchar(). It doesn't pick '\n'. I'm on Windows. I have gone through several blogs which say I should use '\r\n', didn't worked. Tried '\r' alone, didn't worked.
Input file contains this:-
5
Abcde //There is ENTER after 5

Comment: What does your input file contain and what are you taking input from the console? Edit the question saying that. It is not very clear at the moment.

Comment: @vish213 getchar() doesn't read from a file, it reads from stdin. How are you feeding the file to your program ?

Comment: I didn't meant file. I meant running program from console feeding it input from file, as in Program.exe <in.txt >out.txt

Comment: @vish213 It would be better if you edit the question clearly stating the step by step procedures you take in running the program.

Comment: @vish213 You should use `fscanf()`and `fgetc()`.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: I'm just feeding from file for testing purposes.

Comment: @vish213 Whatever purpose be that, `scanf()` and `getchar()` cannot be used to take input from file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution to consume the '\n' left over in stdin after the user typed a number to be read by scanf:

printf("Enter the number: ");
scanf("%u%*c",&n);

In the the scanf() above, the conversion character %*c is telling scanf to read the next character (whatever that be) but, due to the asterisc preceding c, to not store the read character anywhere.

Of course this is only useful if you're trying to get rid only of the '\n', not a of "all whitespaces following the user input".

Hope it helped you folks.