# C scanf not working for multi word input

Tags: c, structure, scanf

I have this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct name
{
    int age;
    char fullname[20];
};

struct name names[20];

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Count of names:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Name %d : ",i);
        scanf("%[^\n]s",names[i].fullname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And when i execute :

```
rupam@linux ~ $ ./a.out 
Count of names:
5
Name 0 : Name 1 : Name 2 : Name 3 : Name 4 : 
rupam@linux ~ $
```

It don't wait for user input. Somehow the `scanf` is not working.

Well, if i use

```
scanf("%s",names[i].fullname);
```

It works for single word inputs.
What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Get rid of the `[^\n]`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Where do you get your spurious `s` for the format string?

Comment: @Deduplicator ah! copy&past.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, adding a space before `%[^\n]s` worked.

Comment: try `scanf(" %[^\n]",names[i].fullname);` : Because newline remaining(of `scanf("%d",&n);`,).

Comment: @Rupam `" %[^\n]s"` : remove `s`. also better `" %19[^\n]"`

Comment: scanf does NOT use regular expressions... delete the `[^\n]`... you are better of writing your own line reading function - working on 1 character at a time because of the way formatted strings work with spaces which can be either tab, space or newline.

Comment: @Anonymouse read reference.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `%19[^\n]` worked magically, but i don't understand it. Can you please explain this.

Comment: read reference. "[character list]" : allow characters. "[^character list]" : Allow character other than the specified. `19` : Number of characters to read maximum.

Comment: @Deduplicator Many people's intuition tell them that `[]` is a modifier for `%s`. That's not true, but it's a common misunderstanding.

Comment: and " "(space) skip white space('\t', '\n', ' '...),

Comment: @unwind: Certainly a valid explanation, though I personally go for C&P error/typo in BLUEPIXY's case, just like he says: I know he knows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets see what happens with the input here.  First, you call `scanf("%d"` to read an integer.  Assuming you enter something like <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `scanf` call will read digits and convert them to an integer.  Since it finds at least one digit, it will succeed, reading that digit and leaving the `\n` from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be read.

Now you go into the loop, where you call `scanf("%[^\n]s"` which attempts to read one or more non-newline characters followed by a newline, then attempts to read an `s`.  Since the next character of input is a newline, this immediately fails (reading nothing), but you don't check the return value of `scanf`, so you don't notice.  You then loop attempting to read more, which will fail again.

So what you need to do is ignore the newline.  The easiest way is probably to just use a space in the format, which causes `scanf` to read and ignore whitespace, until it finds a non-whitespace character;  change your second scanf to:

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]", names[i].fullname);
```

Note some additional changes here.  We got rid of the spurious `s` as you don't particularly want to match an `s` after the name.  We also added a limit of 19 characters to avoid overflowing the `fullname` array (19 characters max + 1 for the terminating NULL byte).

Answer (score 0):

Use getchar() after printf in for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct name
{
    int age;
    char fullname[20];
};

struct name names[20];

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Count of names:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Name %d : ",i);
        getchar();//getchar here
        scanf("%[^\n]s",names[i].fullname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems not as good as just using the `scanf` option to skip whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you *may* work with files with Windows line-ending in the future (redirecting files to stdin), then instead of using one `getchar()` as suggested by @jahan you can use

```
if(getchar()=='\r') getchar();
```

This can increase the portability of your code.

Comment: `\r\n` in a file will be converted to `\n` in stdin, in Windows. However there is no harm in being more permissive. Ideally keep reading until `\n` or `EOF` is hit.

Comment: @Matt McNabb After reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23430040/3488231), I don't think that is necessarily true.

Comment: don't think what is true exactly?

Comment: @Matt McNabb that `\r\n` will be converted to `\n` automatically.

Comment: It's implementation-defined, but all Windows compilers that I know of will do that